# Take a screenshot of a page with Rails or (client side) JS

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, svg

I need to take a screenshot of a webpage when a user creates a new "graph", and save it as a thumbnail for later.

How can I save a screenshot of the page?

Requirements:

1. Take a screenshot of entire webpage, given a URL
2. Must capture correct CSS (both inline and from external stylesheets)
3. Must capture SVG, Canvas, or any other HTML element.

I'm really surprised that no libraries seem to meet these requirements. I've done a lot of research, so I'll be listing every library and which requirement it fails to meet.

Libraries (that don't meet all requirements):

- [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) - doesn't capture external CSS
- [IMGkit](https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit) - doesn't capture external CSS
- [URL2PNG](https://url2png.com/) - $30 a month, and not sure it works.
- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) - requires Node.js

Comment: PhantomJS looks promising, but not sure how I could use this on heroku  with a Rails application: http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots

Comment: Not a duplicate @david. From the accepted answer to that question "as it does not parse nearly as much of the CSS3 attributes I would want it to". It's a good solution, but we use a lot of css3, so need a true screenshot.